# Bazel Typescript - Cannot find ts_library Referenced by module_name

Tags: javascript, typescript, bazel, monorepo

I have two Bazel `BUILD` files:

- server/BUILD
- enums/BUILD

My goal is to import a `ts_library` from enums into server as a dependency for the server `ts_library`. Therefore, I used the approach described here: https://dev.to/lewish/building-a-typescript-monorepo-with-bazel-4o7n (via `module_name` and `deps`)

Enums `BUILD` file:

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "enums",
    srcs = glob(["src/index.ts"]),
    module_name = "@lbm/enums",
)
```

Server `BUILD` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//nodejs:image.bzl", "nodejs_image")
load("@npm_bazel_typescript//:index.bzl", "ts_library")

ts_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = glob(
        include = [ "**/*.ts" ],
        exclude = [ "src/index.ts" ],
    ),
    deps = ["//enums:enums"]
)

ts_library(
    name = "main",
    srcs = [ "src/index.ts" ],
    deps = ["//enums:enums", ":lib"],
)

filegroup(
    name = "libfiles",
    srcs = ["lib"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

filegroup(
    name = "mainfile",
    srcs = ["main"],
    output_group = "es5_sources",
)

nodejs_image(
    name = "server",
    data = [
        ":libfiles",
        ":mainfile",
    ],
    entry_point = ":mainfile",
)
```

But when running

```
bazel run //server:server
```

Although I've set `module_name = "@lbm/enums"` and added `//enums` to the `deps`, I get this error:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //server:server (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: /minimal-bazel-monorepo/server/BUILD:13:1: Compiling TypeScript (devmode) //server:main failed (Exit 1)
server/src/index.ts:2:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@lbm/enums'.

2 import { Constants } from '@lbm/enums';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~

Target //server:server failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.207s, Critical Path: 0.09s
INFO: 0 processes.
```

You can try it yourself: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo

## Edit #1

After updating the import statement from `import { Constants } from '@lbm/enums';` to `import { Constants } from '@lbm/enums/src';`, as stated by [Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11253793), I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@lbm/enums/src/index'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since BUILD file is located in /enums dir and not in /enums/src, the correct TS import would look like this:
   `import { Constants } from '@lbm/enums/src';`
   Or maybe consider moving this BUILD file to /enums/src dir, then TS imports can be left as of now.
2. I noticed from the example that you use yarn workspaces. Unfortunately, they are not supported right now by rules_nodejs, so prob better to have one package.json in the root.

Comment: That makes total sense! But I get another error now (I've updated my question). Will yarn workspaces be supported soon? (because I don't like to have only one `package.json`)

Comment: The second error is just about yarn workspaces. You can fix it by having "main" entry in the root package.json (but probably will need to drop yarn workspaces while fixing it).

Comment: That confuses me. Isn't it the whole point of a monorepo to have multiple packages? ... I've tried it, but the error persists.

Comment: I've couldn't fix it, although I've removed yarn workspaces (same error). Would you mind adding more details? If you want to, you can also create a pull request here: https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo

Comment: looks like yarn workspaces are still there. Maybe you forgot to push?
https://github.com/flolude/minimal-bazel-monorepo/blob/master/package.json#L5

Comment: I pushed it now

Comment: it works now for me. you just have to fix import once again :)

Comment: I'm so dumb. Thank you so much!